# How can I view logs that application write to console on windows

Tags: windows, logging

How can I view logs that application write to console on windows like in mac? In mac i can view console log of any running application in Terminal.

Is it something similar in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

you can use powershell, maybe the simpliest way :

```
PS>Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 10 -EntryType error                                                              

   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message                                                  
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------                                                  
   89289 août 11 08:15 Error       powershellmonitor               1 Erreur : test du template de gestion des erreurs (C:\temp
   89288 août 11 08:13 Error       powershellmonitor               1 Erreur : test du template de gestion des erreurs (C:\temp
   89261 août 11 06:00 Error       WSH                    3221225473 Error MSIEXEC.EXE /i ADOBFLAS11005CX64FR0100.msi /M ADOBF
   89257 août 11 06:00 Error       MsiInstaller                11722 Product: ADOBFLAS11005CX64FR0100 -- Error 1722.There is a
   89231 août 10 06:00 Error       WSH                    3221225473 Error MSIEXEC.EXE /i ADOBFLAS11005CX64FR0100.msi /M ADOBF
   89227 août 10 06:00 Error       MsiInstaller                11722 Product: ADOBFLAS11005CX64FR0100 -- Error 1722.There is a
   89203 août 09 06:00 Error       WSH                    3221225473 Error MSIEXEC.EXE /i ADOBFLAS11005CX64FR0100.msi /M ADOBF
```